# modify network destination address on Pronto 3290

Tags: ip-address, openflow, opendaylight

I've a Pronto 3290 (Open Flow 1.0) and I installed an OpenDayLight Controller.

I'd like to add this type of action: modify network destination address

But when I try to add this flow, this is the result:

```
OFPET_FLOW_MOD_FAILED OFPFMFC_ALL_TABLES_FULL
```

Is there a limitation of the switch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a limitation of the switch. The switch tries to add the flow entry but cannot because all the table(s) are full. Hence, it sends an error message.

Actually, OpenDayLight controller you are using is not brilliant enough to sense the details of tables in the switch. A perfect controller should have noticed the capabilities of the switch like number of tables and number of entries supported in a table and should not have sent a flow mod when the switch's memory is full.

As per openflow 1.3, switch can support 255 tables. I guess 1.0 switch will support a single table. So, try 1.3 supported switches.